# Why uninitialized variable contains garbage instead of ‘nil’?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, initialization

Environment: Mac OS X 10.9, Xcode 5.0.2

I`am create standard Cocoa Application for OS X and disable ARC in project settings. Append one button “Run”:

File “AppDelegate.h”:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)clickRun:(id)sender;

@end
```

File “AppDelegate.m”:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)clickRun:(id)sender
{  
    NSAutoreleasePool* apool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString* pathToFile = @"/Users/admin/1.txt";

    NSError* error;

    NSLog(@"[1] Retain count of Error: %lx", [error retainCount]);

    NSData* dataOfFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile
                                                options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                                  error:&error];

    NSLog(@"[2] Retain count of Error: %lx", [error retainCount]);

    [apool drain];
}
@end
```

When run program and first click button console has output:

“*[1] Retain count of Error: 0*” – of course zero because variable ‘error’ is uninitialized 
"*[2] Retain count of Error: 0*" – second zero tell us what method “dataWithContentsOfFile” is successful read a file.

And debugger all time say what variable ‘error’ has type a ‘nil’.

**But** when I second time click button, debugger break on:

NSLog(@"[1] Retain count of Error: %lx", [error retainCount]);

And show message “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” and variable ‘error’ contains garbage and of course [error retainCount] get like segmentation fault. But this vary strange because if method  “dataWithContentsOfFile” successful, it do not allocate variable ‘error’ and no body touch this variable. 

**From where variable ‘error’ take a garbage and why first click do not contain a garbage?**

Of course after spend several hours I solve this problem, forced (re)initialization of ‘nil’:

```
NSError* error = nil;
```

But question above is not expired.

Comment: So why were you ignoring the compiler warning about an uninitialized variable?

Comment: @Hot Licks 1 XCode generate very many warnings and me already dazzled from warnings ;) in MS Visual Studio C++ shoving warnings more neatly, for me.
2 I read somewhere ;) what dataWithContentsOfFile automatically allocate ‘error’ variable if it needed. But I am not knowed what uninitialized local variables of pointer type contain garbage from stack.

Comment: As a general rule, regardless of what may be claimed for ARC or whatever, when you declare a local variable you should explicitly assign a value to it before "reading" it.  The only reason (besides a teensy performance hit) for not initializing ALL locals when you create them is that sometimes that "uninitialized variable" warning is actually helpful in telling you you missed something.

Comment: Also me confuse a debugger, it showing by first click (run) what variable ‘error’ has type ‘nil’ and contains NSObject. And I am believed what type ‘nil’ means some thing more than zeroed.

Comment: The debugger generally will not even know how to locate a variable before it's initially assigned.  It may come up with garbage, or it may refuse to show you anything.

Comment: As always, http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `error` is declared on the stack.  The feature of initialising strong[1] object references to nil when they are on the stack is an ARC only feature i.e. if you turn it off, the variable will not be initialised anymore.

However, memory allocated on the stack, is zeroed at first and it's only after it is used that it contains garbage.  Also, the garbage itself may coincidentally be zeros.  The first time you enter this method it is possible that the memory was freshly allocated and hence `error` just happened to be nil by luck.  On subsequent invocations, the memory had probably been used by other stack frames, so `error` contained garbage.

Other points:

Sending `-retainCount` to a valid object will never return 0 because `-release` deallocates the object instead of decrementing the count when it is 1.

When you see the pattern

```
 someResult = [someObject blahBlahError: &error];
```

it's technically not allowed to use the value passed back to `error` unless `someResult` is something that indicates an error has occurred.  In your example, you should only be trying to use `error` if `dataOfFile` is set to nil.

[1] Thanks to Nikolai for the clarification.

Comment: +1 — just a note: It is very unlikely to get zeroed memory on the stack when entering a method, even for the first time. The fact that memory pages are zeroed at allocation is true. But is very unlikely that the stack memory was not used before. That happens only if no other function went deeper into the stack than the current.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe True, but we clearly do have zeroed memory on the first time in this case.

Comment: Also: ARC only guarantees nil initialization for `__strong` variables.

Comment: @ JeremyP That is by coincidence and can change any time.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Still true :)

Comment: @ JeremyP Still +1 :) — especially for pointing out correct error-by-reference handling in Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

The variable is not initialized, and local variables of pointer type are not automatically initialized. Normally they will contain what previously was in the stack in their location, so it is completely random, and you can expect anything - including nil, as it happens when the code is run for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you ran the method, the pointer `error` coincidentally was `nil`. Sending a message such as `retainCount` to `nil` returns 0 by definition. It is not the case that there is any object with retain count zero.

The second time you run the method, by coincidence, `error` is not `nil`. Thus, sending a message will be bad access.